# Cantonese 咁: adverb suffix?

Tags: grammar, cantonese

I know 咁 means "so", as in "so big" = "gam daai". However, I just found this sentence:

> 我仲未失望咁係度等
>
> Ngo5 zung6-mei6 sat1-mong6 gam3 hai6 dou6 dang2

In which I think it ought to be interpreted as an adverbial suffix, like English -ly. Maybe it is just because I saw a Mandarin rendition of this which makes it a 地. So can this gam sometimes be used as Mandarin 地? Also, I translated this sentence to:

> I haven't yet been disappointed of being here waiting

Before seeing the Mandarin version. Would that be a valid translation?

Comment: Where did you get the jyutping romanisation? Did you just transcribe it yourself, or did you find it elsewhere? The 咁 feels odd to me (being a native-ish speaker) and I would be inclined to replace it with one of two similar sounding particles. Unfortunately, while I found a recording of the song on YouTube, I haven't been able to catch the specific sounds in question to verify. (The `gam` seems to have been omitted or afforded very little stress.)

Comment: The romanization is self-made. The spellig is from the lyrics of this song in a version posted by a speaker of Hakka on Fb, and that version is full of spelling mistakes. For example, hai can mean to be or at, and they are spelt the same in that version, whereas they should be spelt differently.

Comment: @Maroon those particles you mention, are they 恁 and 噉?

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure which is correct---my Cantonese knowledge is mostly verbal and I never learned to "write" Cantonese---but the sense I get from the dictionary is that those fit the sense I'm looking for. Incidentally, it looks like `hai` here should be "at" (which I suppose you may have alluded to in your comment). I'm guessing that the romanisation is based on the characters, rather than the actual song audio?

Comment: Indeed that hai is misspelt. The romanization is based on the characters, basically a character-by-character translit usig MDBG and CantoDict. Even with it under my eyes I cannot distinguish all the syllables in the recording: much too fast :).

Comment: Btw is dou also misspelt?

Comment: No, dou is right. hai should have an extra mouth radical on the left.

Comment: Yeah, I checked with [my usual dictionary](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/) and it looked fine.

Comment: This sentence sounds a little odd to me, too. Strictly speaking, although 咁 is often translated to "so", it should be perceived as **"that" (emphasis)**, like "I don't know you are **that** stupid." While, this one makes perfect sense to me: `你 慢慢咁 過來啦`, here 咁 indeed can be replaced with 地 in Mandarin and the meaning doesn't change much – but I think the translation that can convey the subtlety in Mandarin should be, `你 慢慢地那樣 過來啦`.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence?  Movie?  It does not sound like natural Cantonese.

Comment: See the answer below fo the sentence's source.

Comment: Precise Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utBNsy7MVAU&index=1&list=RDutBNsy7MVAU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one possible error here (係 v.s. 喺), so I'll assume a nonzero possibility of characters being misassigned. In that case, I'll assume the pronunciation is correct except for the tone.

**I have never heard `gam3` (generally written as 咁) used (correctly) outside of a context where it comes before an adjective as a means of indicating the extent something is `<adjective>`.**

**Conversely, there is also `gam2`, which has the same pronunciation apart from the tone.** (The dictionary gives as 噉.) Use of this `gam2` *alone* (i.e. not in some sort of set phrase like 噉樣) indicates something like "in this case" (e.g. 今日落雨，噉我哋唔好出去啦---*it is raining today, so let's not go out*). (The dictionary also suggests 恁 as a particle with the romanisation `gam` with a meaning that could fit, but the use-case appears identical to 噉, so I cannot differentiate between them.)

**It is worth noting that people seem to sometimes conflate the two**---e.g. 咁樣 and 噉樣 both appear in the Google IME. In fact, 咁嘅 is a lot more common than 噉嘅, judging from Google search and IME suggestions, even though `gam3` is definitely not the right tone. **Thus, it looks like there's some variation in what the correct transcription for a character not used formally is.** (I later found similar ambiguities when I tried checking the character for `zung6`.)

**Regardless of what the correct character is, `gam2` makes more sense, because I can group it with 係 in a way that makes sense to me.** This means that the translation should be something like:

> I still haven't lost hope, so I'm waiting here.

For what it's worth, I'm having a lot of trouble catching any instance of `gam` in the audio of the song ("想你想得好孤寂") in question. If the particle were actually absent, though, the line would not feel complete. (I would interpret it as either *I still haven't lost hope, waiting here* or *I still haven't lost hope that waiting here . . .*)

Comment: Moved from the text: I'm a native Cantonese speaker, so I do not have a very formal knowledge of tones and the such. I'm relying somewhat on a dictionary and my intuition here.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "I have never _heard_ `gam3` [...]"? That "heard" is missing in the first bold part of the answer...

Comment: @MickG: yep, that's it. Thanks for the reminder.